# How to make a "progressbar" similar to Gmail or G+?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-progressbar

> [image]

I could add a simple progressbar to XML activity and put a padding / margin negative, but I think Google inserted directly into the actionbar progressbar.

If I do something like this:

```
Activity act = this;
act.setProgress (20 * 100);
...
```

In the action bar displays a spinner, but I'm interested in one horizontal style bar as does Google. **What is the best solution?**

I am using android-support-v7 to be compatible with older versions (I'm not interested in using libraries like ActionBarSherlock)

Comment: Have a look at [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh).

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in component in Android that does what you want.
I suggest you use the third party [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) instead.